# "Splitting" a matrix in constant time

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, matrix-multiplication, strassen

I am trying to implement Strassen's algorithm for matrix multiplication in C++, and I want to find a way to split two matrices into four parts each in constant time.  Here is the current way I am doing so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        A11[i][j] = a[i][j];
        A12[i][j] = a[i][j+n];
        A21[i][j] = a[i+n][j];
        A22[i][j] = a[i+n][j+n];
        B11[i][j] = b[i][j];
        B12[i][j] = b[i][j+n];
        B21[i][j] = b[i+n][j];
        B22[i][j] = b[i+n][j+n];
    }
}
```

This approach is obviously O(n^2), and it adds n^2*log(n) to the runtime, as it is called for each recursive call.

It seems that the way to do this in constant time is to create pointers to the four sub-matrices, rather than copy over the values, but I am having a difficult time figuring out how to create those pointers.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your source matrix have size 2*n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think of matrices, think of matrix views.

A matrix view has pointer to a buffer of `T`, a width, a height, an offset, and a stride between columns (or rows).

We can start with an array view type.

```
template<class T>
struct array_view {
  T* b = 0; T* e = 0;
  T* begin() const{ return b; }
  T* end() const{ return e; }

  array_view( T* s, T* f ):b(s), e(f) {}
  array_view( T* s, std::size_t l ):array_view(s, s+l) {}

  std::size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }
  T& operator[]( std::size_t n ) const { return *(begin()+n); }
  array_view slice( std::size_t start, std::size_t length ) const {
    start = (std::min)(start, size());
    length = (std::min)(size()-start, length);
    return {b+start, length};
  }
};
```

Now our matrix view:

```
temlpate<class T>
struct matrix_view {
  std::size_t height, width;
  std::size_t offset, stride;
  array_view<T> buffer;

  // TODO: Ctors
  // one from a matrix that has offset and stirde set to 0.
  // another that lets you create a sub-matrix
  array_view<T> operator[]( std::size_t n ) const {
    return buffer.slice( offset+stride*n, width ); // or width, depending on if row or column major
  }
};
```

Now your code does work on `matrix_view`s, not matrices.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a submatrix class that holds the location in the parent matrix of the smaller matrix you want to use.  Mostly just what you already have for your Matrix, except you'd need to store starting indexes for the row and columns, then offset your indexing by those offsets.  If done right the main/root matrix would be a submatrix with the full matrix as the bounds.